# Assign Random Materials to Loose Parts

Tags: python, materials, scripting

I have 5 materials, and I'd like to assign it randomly to loose parts of one object.
Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Do you want to assign images textures or just solid colours randomly?

Comment: Doesn't have to be image textures, just to assign materials already created.
Material 1,2,3,4,5 to random sperate objects. If that could cycle through materials, that'll be cool also. Just want to assign them to loose parts, without going like: Select object, seperate by lose parts, select the part, assign material, repeat 10 times for 1 obj

Comment: This does not answer your question, but you do not have to separate the object in order to assign different materials to different parts.
You just have to create more material slots (in your case 5 total) and select each part and assign it to a different slot, than you can manually set each slot to a different material.
It's not random and it's not automated but at least you don't have to separate the loose parts.

Comment: is it ok if my answer could only be used for multiple separate objects instead of loose parts in one object?

Comment: Ofc, at least it'll lower the clicking count! ^^

Comment: Great! then give me one sec and I will upload the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you already have 5 material slots assigned to the object and the object is your current object, this python script will do what you want:

**Note** This script works whether the object is in object or edit mode, but if it's in object mode, the changes won't show up until you toggle edit mode.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import random
from math import trunc

object = bpy.context.object
if object.mode == 'OBJECT':
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(object.data)
else:
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(object.data)
    

islands = []

bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()

# https://github.com/Aadjou/blender-scripts/blob/master/bmesh-get-linked-faces.py
def get_linked_faces(f):
    if f.tag:
        # If the face is already tagged, return empty list
        return []
    # Add the face to list that will be returned
    f_linked = [f]
    f.tag = True
    # Select edges that link two faces
    edges = [e for e in f.edges if len(e.link_faces) == 2]
    for e in edges:
        # Select all firs-degree linked faces, that are not yet tagged
        faces = [elem for elem in e.link_faces if not elem.tag]
        # Recursively call this function on all connected faces
        if not len(faces) == 0:
            for elem in faces:
                # Extend the list with second-degree connected faces
                f_linked.extend(get_linked_faces(elem))
    return f_linked
#---------------

examined = set()
islands = []

for face in bm.faces:
    face.tag = False

for face in bm.faces:
    if face in examined:
        continue
    links = get_linked_faces(face)
    for linked_face in links:
        examined.add(linked_face)
    islands.append(links)

for island in islands:
    n = trunc(random.uniform(0,5))
    for face in island:
        face.material_index = n

# update the object's mesh from the bmesh
if object.mode == 'OBJECT':
    bm.to_mesh(object.data)
    bm.free()
else:
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(object.data)
```

The script uses the function `get_linked_faces` that is taken from Madlaina Kalunder's Aadjou [github repository](https://github.com/Aadjou/blender-scripts/blob/master/bmesh-get-linked-faces.py).

## How it Works

The script uses `bmesh`, so it starts with the boiler plate to create a bmesh from an object's mesh.  You can replace the line

```
object = bpy.context.object
```

with code to use a different object.  **Note** the script assumes there is an object here.  You might want to protect the rest of the code with

```
if object:
```

After creating the mesh and validating the lookup tables, the `get_linked_faces` function is defined.  It identifies, recursively, every face that is linked to the current face by an edge.  In other words, it identifies the *islands* in the mesh, that is your loose parts.

Next we initialize some variables.  `get_linked_faces` uses a tag field that we clear to `False`.

This is followed by the loop that creates the islands/loose parts by looping through every face in bmesh.

Finally, we loop through all of the created islands, selecting a random color for the island, and assigning it to all of the faces in that island.  **Note** this relies on having exactly five material slots.  It might be more robust to use

```
    n = trunc(random.uniform(0,len(object.material_slots)))
```

but only if you want to use exactly all of the materials assigned to the object.

Finally we end by restoring the object's mesh from the bmesh.  This transfers the data back.

Here's a simple example with an object consisting of 3 cubes, a Suzanne, and a sphere:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the efford. This is just what I was looking for Marty. Appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm glad it worked out for you.

Comment: I'm not particularly great at coding so I was wondering if this works for any amount of material slots as is?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps given below to achieve this result:

[image]

**Note: this method can only be applied when adding solid colours to an object and all the objects have to be separate.**

[image]

Separate all the loose parts in the object by pressing 'P' 'loose parts' in edit mode, go to the shading tab and add in an 'object info' node and our favourite 'colour ramp'.

[image]

plug in the random of the object info node to the factor of the colour ramp and connect the colour of the colour ramp to the 'principled BSDF', change the colours of the colour stop (the arrows) to whatever you want it to be and simply press the '+' icon on the top to add new colour stops.

**Note: do not connect the 'location' of the object info node to the factor of the colour ramp as shown in the GIF. I made a mistake, sorry ;)**

[image]

The shading is finished, now first press the object where this material is assigned to and then press 'A' so that the object with the colour assigned to is in another colour, press 'Ctrl + L' and select the 'materials' options.

Comment: Thank you for this one as well, not exactly what I was looking for, thought it might help.

Comment: Ok no problem Jackie 